# which is correct "at the following" or "on the following"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

i use it when i send link (URL for file or something) for some one, so what is the correct to say

Please find file on the following link
OR
Please find file at the following link

Answer (score 9):

For me, the correct interpretation is *at the following link*.

Why?  Because URL's are "Uniform Resource Locators".  They identify a way of finding something, and you can find that resource *at a location*.

Conversely, *On* serves no purpose (in this context).  If I had a specific server in mind, where I knew a file was, I might say to you "Frodo, you can find that file on Server2".  It's on that server.

But links aren't servers, they are directions and so you can find it *at* that arbitrary-location, irrespective of the real location.

That's my interpretation anyway :)

Comment: Can't you find a file by "clicking on" a link, though?

Answer (score 1):

*on the following* is incorrect.

*at the following* is correct, but verbose.

I would avoid both options and remove "the following link" from the phrase. This part of the sentence actually says nothing. *following* merely confirms that the thing you're talking about is coming up next in the sentence and *link* identifies it as a link, which it obvious.

It's like saying *the following word is a synonym for cat: feline*. Instead, just say *feline is a synonym for cat*.

I would say

*you can find the file at http://...*

or

*you can download the file from http://...*

I personally despise the use of *please find* or its hideous overseer *please find attached*. Consider a terser and more practical tone.

*The report ( http://... ) provides details..."

*Your requested file is now avaialble at http://..."

Comment: I first encountered stylistic advice like this when learning to write legal work.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I can think of to say "on the following", is:

"We picked up the puppy *on the following* Tuesday," or, "The timeshare is available *on the following* dates..."

Use "at" for places - "on" for times.